# how to use css with Suave web

Tags: css, f#, suave

i'm a newbie F# programming,

and now i try to make web with F# and Suave then i follow from [this link](https://theimowski.gitbooks.io/suave-music-store/content/en/)

i have a problem that i cannot use css in my project (see on image)

[id="box" wasn't show on browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCEql.png)

file View.fs

```
let index container =
html [] [
    head [] [
        title [] "Suave Music Store"
        cssLink "/Site.css"
    ]

    body [] [
        div ["id", "header"] [
            tag "h1" [] [
                a Path.home [] [Text "F# Suave Music Store"]
            ]
        ]

        div ["id", "main"] [
            div ["id", "box"] [
                a Path.Store.browse [] [Text "Test Link"]
                tag "h1" [] [
                    a "http://www.google.com" [] [Text "Google"]
                ]
            ]
        ]
        div ["id", "footer"] [
            Text "built with "
            a "http://fsharp.org" [] [Text "F#"]
            Text " and "
            a "http://suave.io" [] [Text "Suave.IO"]
        ]
    ]
]
|> htmlToString
```

and #box in file Site.css

```
#box
{
    border:4px solid #000;
}
```

how i can fix it ?

Comment: At the bottom of the https://theimowski.gitbooks.io/suave-music-store/content/en/css.html page, it talks about making sure the Suave server is serving the `Site.css` file to the client properly, by using `pathRegex`. Have you added that line to your Suave server code yet? If you haven't, then that could be the cause: the browser isn't yet seeing your CSS file.

Comment: yes, i add  pathRegex "(.*)\.(css|png)" >=> Files.browseHome in webPart in file App.fs certainly. but browser see another css such as dot line in footer that is a #footer

Answer (score 3):

This could be a caching issue - if you are changing the CSS file and the browser caches the old version, then recent changes on the server might not be visible.

You can probably configure your browser to avoid caching. Alternatively, you can change your server to send HTTP headers that disable caching (during development and debugging):

```
let noCache =
  Writers.setHeader "Cache-Control" "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
  >>= Writers.setHeader "Pragma" "no-cache"
  >>= Writers.setHeader "Expires" "0"

// And then in your main handler add 'noCache'
pathRegex "(.*)\.(css|png)" >=> noCache >=> Files.browseHome
```